# GORM Many-to-one with mapping table

Tags: mysql, grails, grails-orm, many-to-one

I have a couple of mysql tables with many-to-one relationship which is using a mapping table for the relationship. It is as below

```
book_type_map
Column         Datatype
book_id        Char(36)
book_type_id   Char(36)

book_type
Column         Datatype
book_type_id   Char(36)
book_type      Text
default        TinyInt(1)

books
Column         Datatype
book_id        Char(36)
```

As you can see, the `book` table or the `book_type` table has no columns referring eachother, I need to be able to access `book_type` from the `book`. These are my domain objects for `Book` and `BookType`

```
class Book {
    String id
    BookType bookType

    static mapping = {
        table 'books'
        id column: 'book_id', generator: 'uuid2'
        bookType joinTable: [ name: 'book_type_map',
                key: 'book_id',
                column: 'book_type_id']
    }
}

class BookType {
    String id 
    String type
    Boolean default

    static mapping = {
        table 'book_type'
        id column: 'book_type_id', generator: 'uuid2'
        type column: 'book_type'
    }
}
```

When I run this I get this exception when I do a `Book.findAll()`

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'this_.book_type_id' in 'field list'

I think my mapping is incorrect. I'd appreciate it if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Comment: table 'books' doesn't match the table structure you listed above.  I assume this is a typo?

Comment: it was a typo @ErikAhlswede.

Answer (score 0):

Having a join table in general only makes sense for one-to-many or many-to-many relationships.  In this example, Book can have only one BookType so why does there need to be a join table?  You would just have a column with the BookTypeId.

I think what you are looking for is:

```
class Book {
    String id

    static hasMany = [bookType: BookType]

    static mapping = {
        table 'books'
        id column: 'book_id', generator: 'uuid2'
        bookType joinTable: [ name: 'book_type_map',
                key: 'book_id',
                column: 'book_type_id']
    }
}
```

See the [docs](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/joinTable.html) for more details

**EDIT**

If you are set on this table structure you can flip the relationship (not a fan of this). This structure doesn't really make sense to me, but will work:

```
class Book {
    String id

    static mapping = {
        table 'books'
        id column: 'book_id', generator: 'uuid2'
    }
}

class BookType {
    String id 
    String type
    Boolean default

    static hasMany = [books: Book]    

    static mapping = {
        table 'book_type'
        id column: 'book_type_id', generator: 'uuid2'
        type column: 'book_type'
        books joinTable: [ name: 'book_type_map',
                key: 'book_type_id',
                column: 'book_id']
    }
}
```

Comment: You are right having a join table makes sense for one-to-many or many-to-many relationships. I am not sure how we should map the Many-to-one relationship when there is a mapping table? Would you have any suggestion?

Comment: Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: I did try it. With that I can only get a List/Set of `BookType` instead of a single object of BookType.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, But, I need to be able to access `BookType` from `Book` object. Even I am not a fan of the table structure as well but I cannot change that.